# Centos 7 save iptables settings

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7

Problem: iptables resets to default settings after server reboot.

I'm trying to set rule like this:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`

after that I do:

`service iptables save`

and it writes back something like this

`iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]`

and after this I just ran (this was done once):

`chkconfig iptables on` (I have read that this has to be done in order to restore settings after reboot)

After that I reboot and run this command:

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep iptables`

and I see that iptables.service is enabled, however, the rule (to open port 3000) does not work anymore.

How do I persist these settings?

Comment: Why didn't you just use firewalld? It is probably still running.

Comment: Probably because firewalld is not suited for server environments...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

CentOS 7 is using [FirewallD](http://www.firewalld.org/) now!  Use the `--permanent` flag to save settings.

Example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
```

Then reload rules:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: any idea why centos7 image from AWS AMI does not have firewallD.

Comment: OR you can disable firewalld and install "iptables-services" package to achieve near native iptables compatibility :)

Comment: I tried configuring port forwarding 80 -> 8180 for lo (`--zone=trusted`)  with firewalld-cmd but it does not work (it works in `--zone=public`) Doing so with iptables `sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8180 ; sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8180` works (but each `firewalld --reload` loses undoes this)

Comment: @saad: because aws already provides a firewall service hence the ami can be kept small

Comment: It is not! I have ordered a Centos 7 VPS and it has iptables by default! The OS version: 7.5.1804 (Core)

Answer (score 106):

Disable firewalld by the following command:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Then install iptables-service by following command:

```
yum install iptables-services
```

Then enable iptables as services:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Now you can save your iptable rules by following command:

```
service iptables save
```

Answer (score 32):

On CentOS 7 Minimal you may need to install the `iptables-services` package (thanks to [@RichieACC](https://serverfault.com/users/32584/richieacc) for the [suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings#comment786743_626540)):

```
sudo yum install -y iptables-services
```

And then enable the service using `systemd`:

```
sudo systemctl enable iptables.service
```

And run the initscript to save your firewall rules:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init save
```

Answer (score 8):

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

will save the current configuration without the need to install any other libraries or services.

Comment: From its `manpage` : `iptables-save — dump iptables rules to stdout`.  It doesn’t save anything unless you redirect it to some file.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify directly the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file.
Reload the `iptables` service to reload the rules from that file.

Yet, as you were told already, `firewalld` is the new default firewall system for Centos, and this is a good chance to learn how to use it, don't you think?

Comment: in CentOS7 there is no more a /etc/sysconfig/iptables file

Comment: Sorry @roothahn , but it definitely exists... unless you miss some packages of course. From /usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service you can see that what's actually launched is "/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start", which is the usual old and dear script looking for the usual old configuration file in /etc/sysconfig

Comment: Yeah `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` doesn't exist for me either.  However, `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` does exist.  But it does not have firewalls rules inside of it as it the `iptables` file had before.

Comment: Pretty strange, have you got a default install? The iptables solution is still officially supported, as even stated on the RHEL7 manual. Do you have the iptables package installed? What about the systemd service? By the way, iptables-config should contain only parameters relevant to the service, such as the iptables modules to load, or options like saving the rules upon service restart.

Comment: I found that the file was not there on a default, minimal install either.  CentOS 7 does not install iptables.service by default, it seems.  "yum install -y iptables.service" installed the service and created a default /etc/sysconfig/iptables for me.

Comment: That should be "yum install iptables-services"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a script like this would have been helpful to anyone?

**Beware that you will loose anything currently configured because it removes firewalld and flushes any current rules in the INPUT table**:

```
yum remove firewalld && yum install iptables-services

iptables --flush INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT            # Any packages related to an existing connection are OK
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT   # ssh is OK
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT   # Port 3000 for IPv4 is OK
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT # any other traffic is not welcome - this should be the last line
service iptables save       # Save IPv4 IPTABLES rules van memory naar disk
systemctl enable iptables   # To make sure the IPv4 rules are reloaded at system startup
```

I guess you want the same in case your system might be reached (now or anytime later) by IPv6 traffic:

```
ip6tables --flush INPUT
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT            # Any packages related to an existing connection are OK
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT   # ssh is OK
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT   # Port 3000 for IPv6 is OK
ip6tables -A INPUT -j REJECT # any other traffic is not welcome - this should be the last line
service ip6tables save       # Save IPv6 IPTABLES rules van memory naar disk
systemctl enable ip6tables   # To make sure the IPv6 rules are reloaded at system startup
```