# How to save iptables configuration on Redhat Enterprise Server 7

Tags: iptables, rhel7

I have a Redhat server (`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)`) that resets iptable rules on re/boot.

According to the [version 6 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables-Saving_IPTables_Rules.html), I execute:

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

which returns:

```
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

If I understand the message correctly, I attempted the following:

```
sudo systemctl iptables save
```

which returns:

```
Unknown operation 'iptables'.
```

I cannot locate the [version 7 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/index.html) on saving ip tables specifically, but previous versions support the same command.

> **What command should I run to save iptables config?**

**For reference:**

firewall d satatus:

```
systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: [Similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings) for CentOS 7

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should install `iptables-services` package.

Then `service iptables save` will work. Also these commands will work too:

```
# iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# ip6tables-save > /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables
```

AFAIK, systemctl doesn't have any option to save iptables-services' configuration.

Note: systemctl syntax is as follow : `systemctl <operation> <unit>`

Comment: By the way, i do not recommend above ways if the rule changes are permanent. I choose to keep comments about rules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file that system administrators should do in order to provide information for future administrators or just a reminder. If you save the configuration with above commands, comments will be lost. Simply use a text editor to edit the file and reload the service with systemctl.

Comment: It's annoying that there is not consistency in this area by know. `systemctl save iptables`, should be a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is link to Security Guide for Red Hat 7:
[using_firewalls](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls)

I use

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

And status of **firewalld** service:

```
# systemctl status firewalld
Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-04-13 10:00:18 CEST; 31min ago
```

So I think, you could also **enable firewalld** service:

```
systemctl start firewalld
systemctl enable firewalld
```

And change rules
via **firewall-config**

1. Press **Super**
2. Type **firewall**,
3. Select **Permanent** in drop down menu
4. Put necessary settings

Comment: the question is about iptables, not firewalld