# why iptables won't deactivate on centos7

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a directadmin server running on centos 7 machine. it's running for years.
We have our own firewall on the network so we don't need linux firewall anymore but I faced to some problems during deactivating the iptables.

I deactivated iptables using "service iptables stop" or "systemctl stop iptables " and "systemctl disable iptables", nothing happened an I still wasn't able to ping the server from outside.
Then I ran "iptables -F" and right after that, the server was inaccessible. nither the site nor the ssh was accessible after that and I shoud connect using vnc.

I'm looking fowrard fo a easy way to get rid of any kind of firewall on the linux and I want all ports and protocols remain open.

Please help me doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CentOS uses something called firewalld

[Link to homepage](https://firewalld.org/)

To stop it use:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Then test your connection and permanently disable with

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

It should automatically flush any existing rules.

Comment: Previously I disabled firewalld on this system and iptables is active.
When I run "iptables -L" it lists all the rules. In [this thred](https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings) was said about installing iptables on centos 7 and also said iptables rules are store in "/etc/sysconfig/iptables" but there is not such file that I can remove the rules.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember CentOS7 by default use firewalld

if you want to disable firewalls & security of Linux system please use below mentioned commands

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl disable iptables
systemctl stop iptables
systemctl mask iptables
```

to disable SE Linux (temporarily until reboot)

```
setenforce 0
```

if you still face any issue please provide us errors